# Using a coder with wildcard generics

Tags: apache-beam

I have a transformation which outputs a type with a wildcard: `Feature<? extends Geomery>`. I have specified a coder for this class and created a pipeline.

```
    final Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create();

    final TypeDescriptor<Feature<? extends Geometry>> featureTypeDescriptor =
            new TypeDescriptor<Feature<? extends Geometry>>() {
            };
    pipeline.getCoderRegistry().registerCoderForType(featureTypeDescriptor, FeatureCoder.of());

    final List<String> data = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
    final PCollection<Feature<? extends Geometry>> features =
            pipeline.apply(Create.of(data).withCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of()))
                    .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, Feature<? extends Geometry>>() {
                        @ProcessElement
                        public void process(ProcessContext processContext) {
                            final String name = processContext.element();
                            processContext.output(new FeatureImpl(name));
                        }
                    }));

    pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
```

When I run this pipeline, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.beam.sdk.repackaged.com.google.common.reflect.Types$WildcardTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.TypeVariable
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderRegistry.getCoderFromTypeDescriptor(CoderRegistry.java:623)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderRegistry.getCoderFromParameterizedType(CoderRegistry.java:656)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderRegistry.getCoderFromTypeDescriptor(CoderRegistry.java:618)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderRegistry.getCoder(CoderRegistry.java:252)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.inferCoderOrFail(PCollection.java:149)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.finishSpecifyingOutput(PCollection.java:89)
```

This can be traced back in the Beam code to the following line in `org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderRegistry#getCoderFromTypeDescriptor` where type gets eventually assigned to `? extends Geometry`:

```
else if (type instanceof WildcardType) {
  // No coder for an unknown generic type.
  throw new CannotProvideCoderException(
      String.format("Cannot provide a coder for type variable %s"
      + " (declared by %s) because the actual type is unknown due to erasure.",
      type,
      ((TypeVariable<?>) type).getGenericDeclaration()),
      ReasonCode.TYPE_ERASURE);
}
```

The example below is a simplification of the real problem. In reality, I do not read from a list of strings but from HBase, so I cannot simply specify my coder in `Create.of(data).withCoder(...)`. However, the behavior is the same.

Is this expected behavior and should I avoid using wild cards? Or should I approach this in another way? Why is my specified coder not used for this?